# Fast report amount of copies

Tags: c++, fastreport

Fast report: how to set amount of document copies to be printed via c++ but not via standard parameters interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the fr3 file (I use Fast Report 4.8)

Just go in menu : Report -> Options and set Copies

or you can set it by code

```
  frxReportFR.PrintOptions.Copies := Copies;
```